# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 49028 into shape (28,28) [working with CNN model]

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory, reshape

I'm trying to create a CNN model to predict off of the dataset that I have for drones. I'm entirely new to this and keep running into the same or similar errors regarding the shaping of the variables in order to train the model.

This is the additional error: ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_1" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 784, 28, 28), found shape=(None, 1751, 28). Which I'm trying to solve via reshaping the variables but have had little luck.

I've looked at other solutions online and have not had much help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.